# Regex for matching between a colon and last newline prior to next colon

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, stringr, regex-greedy

I am trying to parse a string with regex to pull out information between a colon and the last newline prior to the next colon. How can I do this?

```r
string <- "Name: Al's\nPlace\nCountry:\nState\n/ Province: RI\n"
stringr::str_extract_all(string, "(?<=:)(.*)(?:\\n)")
```

but I get:

```r
[[1]]
[1] " Al's\n" " \n"  " RI\n"
```

when I want:

```r
[[1]]
[1] " Al's\nPlace\n" " \n"  " RI\n"
```

Comment: Try `stringr::str_match(string, "(?s)Name:(.*)Country:(.*)State\\s*/\\s*Province:(.*)")`

Comment: How about such as [`:((?:.*\\n)+?)(?=.*:|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZUzN8V/2)

Comment: @bobblebubble Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after as your wanted output looks a bit different.

```
:((?:.*\\n?)+?)(?=.*:|$)
```

- `:` match a colon
- `((?:.*\n?)+?)` match and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) [lazily](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) any lines (to optional `\n`)
- `(?=.*:|$)` until there is a line with colon [ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZUzN8V/3)